# How is it possible to buy and publish a Q1 paper?

Tags: publications, journals, plagiarism, cheating

A few days ago I saw an advertisement that claimed that they could write and publish Q1-Q4 (Q: Quartile) Research paper (with various prices e.g. 200$-500$) in less than 6 months and sell it to anyone (as the author of that paper) who wants a Research paper like last year PhD students, academic peoples, M.Sc. students, etc.

**Q1:** I wonder how it is possible that they are so confident that their paper will be published in less than 3-6 months?

**Q2:** How it is possible to buy and publish a Q1 Research paper?

**Q3:** Does this count as plagiarism?

Comment: What is a “Q1” paper?

Comment: @DanRomik I presume a paper in a Q1 journal, i.e., one in the first quartile of a certain ranking.

Comment: @DanRomik That appears on this site all the time.  https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/115120/how-is-the-scimago-journal-ranking-q1-q4-defined Were you asking rhetorically?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist no, it was a genuine question. I must have missed those discussions.

Comment: I didn’t know what it meant either.  No one reads every post here.

Comment: If you are contemplating buying such a thing. Stop. No, just Stop.

Comment: @Buffy: you mean me?

Comment: Well, anyone, actually. But your comment, below, about believing such claims had me a bit worried.

Comment: Thanks, But I never use that whether it is real or scam (It is against to my ethics). I want to stop them from scamming.

Comment: @DanRomik Q1 is the type of papers that some heads of departments demand from their researchers. Don't ask what that's to do with science, ask what that's to do with metrics.

Comment: Q1: we do not know. Q2: criminal energy finds a way [apologies to Jurassic Park] Q3: It's probably worse than even plagiarism (IMHO). Also, if you need data to write such papers, chances are these data are fake, it is difficult to produce good data in 3-6 months, even when just simulating/modeling. So, it may include falsification of results.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs, careful there. Good PIs with NSF funding do hire people to help them with the data and such. Not the same as this, of course.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs yes, agreed. Or perhaps the best advice should be simply “don’t ask”...

Comment: @Buffy OP says: "write and publish [...] sell it to anyone" - normally, a grant is given to a person with a track record for a given project. There is no evidence here that this is research directed to a particular scientific direction, there is no evidence that buyer needs to have any expertise or track record, there is every evidence that this is research without input by buyer, carried out on contract and "gifted" to the buyer. I think there is no ambiguity whatsoever here. It were differently if the ad was for a research contractor, but academic rules would have to be applied then.

Comment: @DanRomik Lucky the people who need to ask, that's all I am saying.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs indeed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. This sounds like a scam, so I doubt you'll get whatever they promise
2. It's possible (though unlikely and unethical) for anyone capable of producing the research to exchange money for an edited author list, but the problem of finding a buyer in the same area of your expertise is not trivial and probably doesn't make for a profitable strategy unless... See above
3. Absolutely yes. It's plagiarism to claim someone else's work as your own, even if you pay them for it.

Comment: But they convincing the applicant by showing the older customers paper.

Comment: And if it is a scam, so why no one complained after 10 years activity?

Comment: @C.F.G No one who tried the service would likely complain publicly for the fear of then being charged of academic misconduct by their university or community.

Comment: @C.F.G What stops them from taking *any* published paper and say they produced it?

Comment: @BryanKrause: By a simple search and following up using paper author, address, e-mail one can check their claim. But they don't tell the exact paper title and author name. Anyway, someone who is retired or is poor talented student can write paper and sell it.

Comment: @C.F.G You're going to follow up with the author "Hey, did you pay someone $500 to write this for you?" That's an accusation of major misconduct. "they don't tell the exact paper title and author name" - then they haven't shown you *anything* they can produce. I can't tell if you are just trolling here, but this is an obvious, obvious scam.

Comment: Anyone can *write* a paper if someone else has already done the research. This is called "ghostwriting". Pharmaceutical companies are often guilty of this (although it costs much more than $500 and the actual writer is still on the author list). But no one has go from zero to a published Q1 paper in three months, including coming up with the research topic, doing the research and submitting the paper. Its just not possible to do so reliably. And anyone who could would be a superstar academic and make much more than $500 for it.

Comment: I think I found the advertisement in question, and it's worded so ambiguously that the offer could be anywhere on the spectrum from a legitimate proofreading, copyediting, and translation service to out-and-out ghostwriting-type (and ghostresearching-type) plagiarism.

Comment: 'probably doesn't make for a profitable strategy' It'd be fairer to say that the business model depends on the same prerequisite as essay mills for undergraduate assignments, that there exists a ghostwriter who is sufficiently more skilled than the client (in the client's own discipline) that the arrangement works, yet whose labour is valued so low that the client can afford to hire them.  I've occasionally wondered whether students who use essay mills go on to subcontract the work they're assigned in their graduate jobs on a similar basis; this question seems to indicate the answer is "yes".

Comment: @C.F.G Ask them for proof in the form of details about their older papers that are not available in the actual published paper. Not half written manuscripts (I could easily produce those out of Albert Einstein's papers), but something like raw data. If they send something and it makes sense (e.g. raw data that fits the published results), ask the authors of the paper to send you the same. If they are the same, they might tell the truth - or they asked the author for raw data as well, and got it. If they are not, you can uncover their lies.

Comment: @IanSudbery: I am agree with you about ghostwriting. But they write in any field and not just in medical field and pharmaceutical companies. For example, I called one of them for price and they told me that they done this (publishing Q1 paper) for a computer student for 500$ and also told me that their small company have a few ready to publish papers in hand in various fields!!

Comment: ghostwriting (writing for someone else?) is plagiarism?

Comment: Also to clear up some of this discussion about ghostwriting. My understanding of ghostwriting is the following scenario: a scientist does all the actual research, and can summarized the results in, say, a talk on their own. But they don't do the final writing, and pay someone just to write up the paper about their results (acceptable in industry perhaps). This is not the same as producing a paper, and in no way would it require 6 months. What the OP described does not sound like ghostwriting to me, it sounds like generating a paper from scratch and selling it.

Comment: There is just no way a company can produce a Q1 paper in any field, on-demand, without anyone already having done the research. In some fields it might be possible to fabricate results, but to do that well enough to get in a Q1 journal will be hard, and if you are spotted, you are in even more trouble. In things like CS, where you'd have to make your code available, I don't see how even that would be possible. One real test would be, are they will to wait for publication before being paid?

Comment: Ghostwriting is ethically unclear. By many journals definitions of "author", just writing the words is not sufficient contribution to be an author, and it is entirely possible to be an author without writing the words. Despite that, many would regard it as ethically dodgy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, certainly it would be plagiarism. And no one can guarantee publishing in a quality journal. So it is just false advertising. Let the buyer beware.

I also suspect that any buyer would be caught out.

But you can try to sell most things, whether it is ethical or not. Few laws would counter it.

Comment: But they convincing the applicant by showing the older customers paper.

Comment: @C.F.G that is their claim, but why would you believe scammers?

Comment: "And no one can guarantee publishing in a quality journal."  That's obviously wrong.  The guarantee can be "We guarantee we will publish in X or you get your money back."

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist, hmmm. no, it is actually correct. You suggest something entirely different, thank you very much.

Comment: What do you think "guarantee" means, then?

Comment: @C.F.G why would you believe that they actaully wrote the paper they are saying they did?

Comment: @IanSudbery: Since it isn't impossible.

Comment: @C.F.G thats not how proof works. Just because something is possible (and I don't believe this is), does mean some who said they did it are telling the truth. If I was going to risk my entire future, I'd want better proof than just "it isn't impossible"