# Peer-review duration and journal quartiles

Tags: mathematics, peer-review, journals, paper-submission

Does the journal's quartile have anything to do with the peer-review duration?

While reading papers in my discipline, which is Mathematics, I found out that often Q1 ranked journals take about a year, Q2 about half a year. While Q3 and Q4 journals take about three months.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/115120/how-is-the-scimago-journal-ranking-q1-q4-defined

Comment: I would say, to some extent it is true. For example, top mathematics journals like Annals of Math., American Journals, Duke math journals, Invent math etc all belongs to quartile Q1 and all takes sufficient time to check article before giving nod to pass the acceptance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Review time is more a function of how active the editorial board are and how complex the paper is than it is of the journal's impact.